# Publish a react component wrote with TypeScript to npm, but get undefined while import it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack, npm-publish

I tried to publish my own react component wrote with TypeScript to npm. I published it succussfully, but when I created a new react project and import the npm package which I built, some error occured:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yygtJ.png)

But I am sure that I did'nt misuse the named export and default export.
So I think maybe something wrong with my webpack config or tsconfig.

my webpack.config.json

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.tsx'),
  target: 'web',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        use: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules/'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
}
```

my tscongig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "typeRoots": [
      "dist/index.d.ts",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/*",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myname",
  "version": "1.0.42",
  "description": "some text",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode production"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "some url"
  },
  "author": "secret",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.41.23",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "webpack": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

and my entry point index.tsx

```
import someComponent from './someComponent';

export { someComponent };
```

and I am sure that someComponent is default export from other file.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: The error talks about the App component, maybe you should show us how it looks like?

Comment: @DennisVash App component is the default component created by create-react-app, I just import my package published to npm and  at the top and use it in return block.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the solution for me was to make sure that I run `npm run build` before running `npm publish`. This is to ensure that the types are generated correctly before publishing. My scripts in package.json look like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build:types": "tsc --emitDeclarationOnly",
    "build": "npm run build:types && webpack --mode production",
    "refreshVSToken": "vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc"
  },
```